# Make paragraphs inside div continuously appear one by one using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code on my html:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="animate" class="slide">
      <p>Some paragraph.</p>                 
      <p>Some paragraph</p>
              ...
      <p>Some paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    document.addEventListener("click", function(){
       if (i==n) { $("#container").show(); $("#animate").addClass("slide");}
                      ...
       if (i==1) { some code;}
    });
 });
```

*Please do not mind the 'some code' there as I think it is not relevant.*

Anyway, I also have this on an external stylesheet:

```
.slide p{
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% { transform: translateY(100%);}
    100%{ transform: translateY(0%);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}
}
```

So when the user clicks his/her mouse nth time, the `<div>` will appear and trigger the animation. However, what happens is that all paragraphs will appear at the same time (as I still don't know how to animate it one-by-one).

**Question:** Is it possible for it to animate the paragraphs one at a time and continuously (without further/additional clicking), appearing like an ending credit in movies?

**EDIT**

To *clarify*: By I mean continuously, it means like, for an example, that first paragraph will appear and do the animation first. After some time, it will disappear on the screen then the next paragraph will come in... and so on. Without further clicking from the user, the paragraphs would continuously appear and disappear one after another until the last paragraph.

Comment: var myInterval = setInterval(function(){},delay_in_ms);

Comment: @ChrisS. Where should this be placed? I tried placing it anywhere on the script side, it didn't work.

Comment: You write a function that toggles from your currently active P to the next one (or to the first, if you reached the end). the setInterval would then call said function each X milliseconds.

Comment: not entirely clear what the desired behavior is. `continuously` can be interpreted several ways

Comment: @charlietfl, continuously means that, for example, that first paragraph appears first. Then after some time, that paragraph will disappear and then the next comes in, appearing something like an ending credit in movies.

Comment: And after the last paragraph, should it start again? Or should it run only once?

Comment: The whole thing will run only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other way using JQuery You can try this....

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    $('#animate p:first').slideDown(1000, AnimatePara);
});

function AnimatePara(){
    $(this).slideUp(1000);

    $(this).next('p').slideDown(1000, AnimatePara);
}
```

CSS:

```
p{display:none;}
```

Here is jsfiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/30q3gh36/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/30q3gh36/4/

Comment: It's almost close but... is it possible that when the next paragraph animates, the previous paragraph will disappear, appearing like all paragraphs appear and animate then disappear one at a time, one after another? I've edited my question for clarity. Thank you

Comment: This is doing same thing what you need. See the updated jsfiddle previous jsfiddle path was wrong by mistake.  Sorry for that :-)

Comment: Oh my God, this is perfect! So, with this, I'm animating using JQuery instead of CSS, right? @WebArtifice, thank you!